# Can we access Facebook Graph API via script

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a simple script (node) that each day collects information from various APIs, including Facebook's Graph API.

The idea is simple, each day I want to collect the total friend count of my personal account, total page likes of my managed pages, total social interactions of my content (personal and from pages).

Now, if I was doing this in a web app, the normal route would be using facebook login to request the access tokens for my profile and pages, but since this is a script it does not have a public exposed url to return the authentication to.

Does anyone know of a way to manually get the tokens, to use in a scenario like this?

Thanks

Comment: You can manually create tokens in Graph API Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use [this node package](https://github.com/criso/fbgraph)?

> If you get an accesstoken via some other Oauth module like everyauth ,
>   connect-auth or node-oauth you can just set the access token directly.
>   Most get calls, and pretty much all post calls will require an
>   access_token

There is also a decent [article on Medium](https://medium.com/@TheBigFatNoob/working-on-facebooks-graph-api-using-node-js-4bd107ad8c61#.un82qnv2n) which works through this process.

Comment: I've looked at that package, but since this is to be run as a simple script I don't have a URL I can give facebook's API to return after the authentication.